# Как удобнее прописать аргументы в функции python

Tags: python, функции, аргументы

У меня имеется 2 файла: catch.py (Основной), и так же settings.py

Основная моя задача состоит в том, что-бы человек в settings.py мог написать своё сообщение со всеми нужными ему переменными и значениями, и оно импортировалось в catch.py, но из за того, что в settings.py эти переменные не прописанны, выдаётся ошибка, поэтому я ничего лучше не придумал, как добавить это всё в функцию

Но в функции эти значения постоянно приходится добавлять, и их там уже накопилось достаточно много:

```
def vkMsg(ac_id, ac_id_url, ac_price, real_ac_price, seller, lvl, money, chest_text, items, vk, mail, regs, timestamp, year, month, day, hour, minute, second, ac_description):
    return f"""----
 ID Аккаунта: {ac_id}
 Ссылка на аккаунт: {ac_id_url}

 Цена/Реальная цена: {ac_price} Руб/{real_ac_price} Руб

 Информация

 Продавец: {seller}
 Уровень аккаунта: {lvl}
 Вирты: {money}
 Описание: {ac_description}
 Наличие сундука: {chest_text}
 Предметы:
 {items}
 ----"""
```

Вопрос: Как можно это всё упростить?

Comment: Прикрепите данный код в текстовом формате, с помощью 3 кавычек, а не фотографии.

Comment: вот такая штука вам не подойдёт ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: Можно засунуть все эти (ещё много какие) переменные в словарь и передавать его. Или хранить имена "переменных" в самом текте (например так: `ID Аккаунта: %ac_id%`) и заниматься их подстановкой в самой программе на этапе импорта или вывода сообщений.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо всех параметров использовать `**args`:

```py
def vkMsg(**args):
```

А внутри перебрать `for`.